# Identify Microsoft Authenticode Certificate

Tags: certificate, clickonce, authenticode

I have a `Code Signing Certificate` but it looks like I can't use it for Microsoft `ClickOnce`. It looks like `ClickOnce` requires the certificate to be an `Authenticode Certificate`. How can I tell that a (code signing) certificate is indeed an `Authenticode Certificate`?

Answer (score 0):

The only EKU that ClickOnce checks for (as far as I can tell) is `id-kp-codeSign` (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3).  You also need `DigitalSignature` as a (non-extended) Key Usage.  And, of course, a way of getting at the private key.